# Firefox: Page-break table in multi-column layout (CSS)

Tags: html, css, firefox, multiple-columns

I have a HTML/CSS two-column layout that contains a table. Chrome and Edge both break the table in order to provide a balanced column length. However, Firefox refuses to break the table. As an effect one column is much longer than the other.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jxk7f8er/6/
HTML:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <table>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bla</td><td>Bla</td></tr>
  </table>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  column-count:2;
}
```

Chrome and Edge render two columns. Firefox only renders one column.

Is there a way to make Firefox break the table in order to achieve a balanced multi-column layout?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `column-count` here? A `table` (which you are already using) will make this layout for you

Comment: Also if your table is a one column table, are you sure it is tabular data?  Otherwise you shouldn't really use a table (unless this is for an email template, in which case column count won't work in the email clients).  Also firefox only has partial support for columns: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn: known issue - *Firefox does not split tables into columns*

Comment: 1. Column count is not used for the table, it is used for the surrounding container/document. This document (in the original use-case) not only contains the table, but also text.
2. This is a minimal example illustrating the problem. In the actual table has more than one column.

Comment: I updated the example for better resemblance of the original scenario. I want to make clear again: when talking about columns I do not refer to the table. I refer to the surrounding layout.